# how to display asp pages on server without iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssh, server

Im using ssh&xming to upload files to my server. I have no access to the settings of the server, so I dont know if IIS is installed.

Im trying to run a asp.net project on my server, but all I get when Im trying to run the webpage is the source code.

how can I display the page? is there any way to install IIS on SSH without any access to the settings of the server? or to upload some other file to the server that can help run aspx files?
how to display asp pages on server without iis
thanx

Comment: What is the permission you get from the server administrator? If you are not authorized to install IIS, this question is impossible to be answered.

Comment: I dont know whats my permission from the admin...
I have authorization to upload files... how can I check whats my permission? and how can I install IIS on the server?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot install IIS (or anything else) if you don't have administrator access to the server.

And no you cannot run aspx files without IIS. Maybe, just maybe there are ways to do that if you really wanted to, but I'm not aware of that. And why should you? That's like trying to make a boat fly while there are already airplanes available.